# Examples of an unbounded measurable subset of finite measure of the p-adic number field

Tags: measure-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q}_p$ be the p-adic number field, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ its ring of integers.
A subset of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is called bounded if it is contained in a compact subset. Let $\mu$ be the Haar measure on $\mathbb{Q}_p$ such that $\mu(\mathbb{Z}_p) = 1$. I would like to know an example of an unbounded  measurable subset whose measure is finite with respect to $\mu$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of such a set is $$\bigcup_{n\ge 0} p^{-n} (1 + p^{2n+1} \mathbb{Z}_p).$$

Comment: How do you prove it's  unbounded?

Comment: If it were contained in compact $C$, $C$ would have the open cover $\cup_{n\ge 0} \ \ p^{-n} \mathbb{Z}_p$, but this can have no finite subcover, contradicting compactness of $C$.